# Unable to Create Math object in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to create an object of the Math in Java. Ideally there is no need of creating such an instance as it only has static methods and parameters. I just want to create it whether it will allow me or not. So when I am creating a math class object, compiler error is displayed saying that the Math class constructor is not visible.

But I looked into the Math class code and there is no explict constructor provided, so java will provide a default constructor, which can be accessed outside.

Comment: Please, could you post your code?

Answer (score 5):

This is correct behavior. The [constructor for `Math`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Math.java#Math.%3Cinit%3E%28%29) is `private` as it only contains `static` utility methods:

```
private Math() {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I just want to know what are the utility methods in java

Comment: They are exactly as you see in `Math`. Stateless helper methods that typically have no dependency on instance variables or _state_ and are deterministic. Also see this [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/479357/java/java/utility-methods)

Answer (score 2):

This is from Java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html).

```
public final class Math {

    /**
     * Don't let anyone instantiate this class.
     */
    private Math() {}
}
```

The documentation comment itself is sufficient to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the Math class definition, its constructor is private:

```
private Math() {}
```

This means that the creator of the class does not want the user to be able to create instances of this class. It makes sense because it's a utility class, which means any method inside the class does not depened on the state of the object. You just need to pass the method parameter values and it will simply give you the intended result. That's why all the methods inside the Math class are static.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it because its constructor is private. You don't see the constructor in the API because private methods are not listed.

For example take this example:

```
public class SampleClass {

    private static int var1 = 1;
    private static int var2 = 1;
    private static int var3 = 1;


    private SampleClass () {
        // This constructor will prevent the default constructor from being invoked
    }

    public static void runMethod1() {
        System.out.println("Value is:" + var1);
    }

    public static void runMethod2() {
        System.out.println("Value is:" + var2);
    }

    public static void runMethod3() {
        System.out.println("Value is:" + var3);
    }

}
```

You can only create an instance of this class from inside the same class. If you try to create it from elsewhere, you will fail.

Comment: Update based on the example given.